# How do I program a fan in a platformer game?

Tags: physics, platformer, gameobject, godot, jumping

**Fan physics**

I have a platformer game and want to have fans in it that blow in a given direction and if the player presses the jump button they can go even further.

How do I do this?

side note:

I am working with godot engine

**EDIT**

My character moves on the two axes using two variables, both multiplied by speed: move_dir and y_velo. gravity affects y_velo and the arrow keys affect move_dir

Comment: There are different ways to handle object movement in Godot. Can you add more details about how you implemented your movement so far so we can suggest a solution which fits into what you have already done?

Comment: I would define either an Area2D or a Polygon2D which represents the area in which the fan affects objects. Then use a signal to detect when the player or any object enters the affected area and change it's velocity according to the air flow of the fan.